# Modifying query with multiple subqueries to use JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join

I would like to modify the following query to remove the sub queries and instead make use JOIN construct

```
SELECT COUNT(locationid) FROM Passages WHERE PassageTime <= 1485924396 
AND LicenceTag NOT IN (SELECT LicenceTag FROM participant_licencetag WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(passagetime) BETWEEN from_datetime AND to_datetime) 
AND LocationId NOT IN (SELECT LocationId FROM imagefetchrequests WHERE passagetime BETWEEN StartTime AND EndTime);
```

The following is the query that was created by me using JOIN but the results are not comparable with that of the initial query

```
SELECT COUNT(p.locationid) FROM Passages p
LEFT JOIN participant_licencetag pl ON p.LicenceTag = pl.LicenceTag
LEFT JOIN imagefetchrequests ifr ON p.LocationId = ifr.LocationId 
WHERE p.PassageTime <= 1485924396
AND pl.LicenceTag IS NULL AND ifr.LocationId IS NULL 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.passagetime) BETWEEN pl.from_datetime AND pl.to_datetime
AND p.passagetime BETWEEN ifr.StartTime AND ifr.EndTime;
```

What might be going wrong?

Comment: try to apply inner join

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the conditions as part of left joined table within on clause

Something like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(p.locationid) FROM Passages p
LEFT JOIN participant_licencetag pl ON p.LicenceTag = pl.LicenceTag AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.passagetime) BETWEEN pl.from_datetime AND pl.to_datetime
LEFT JOIN imagefetchrequests ifr ON p.LocationId = ifr.LocationId AND p.passagetime BETWEEN ifr.StartTime AND ifr.EndTime
WHERE p.PassageTime <= 1485924396
AND pl.LicenceTag IS NULL AND ifr.LocationId IS NULL;
```

Comment: You may also try this  
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(p.locationid) FROM Passages p
LEFT JOIN participant_licencetag pl ON p.LicenceTag = pl.LicenceTag
WHERE p.PassageTime <= 1485924396
AND pl.LicenceTag IS NULL 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(p.passagetime) BETWEEN pl.from_datetime AND pl.to_datetime
UNION
SELECT COUNT(p.locationid) FROM Passages p
LEFT JOIN imagefetchrequests ifr ON p.LocationId = ifr.LocationId 
AND ifr.LocationId IS NULL
AND p.passagetime BETWEEN ifr.StartTime AND ifr.EndTime
)